# Label beside line before a branching node in a TiKZ "tree" chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm very, very new to TiKZ.

I'd like to make the (very crude) following diagram with TiKZ:

```
   Start
     |
     | Process 1
     |
    /        /         /         Item   Item
         |
         | Process 2
         |
        /            /             /             Item    Item
```

And while Section 18 of the TiKZ manual has been very useful for making the diagram above without the Process labels, I can't find anything on how to add the labels where I want.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {start}
    child {
      child {
        node {item 1}
      }
      child {
        node {item 2}
        child {
          child {
            node {item 3}
          }
          child {
            node {item 4}
          }
        }
      }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or should I be taking a different approach to create this diagram?

[image: mwe output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `edge from parent node`s at the end of a child.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \node {start}
    child {
      child { node {item 1} }
      child { node {item 2}
        child {
          child { node {item 3} }
          child { node {item 4} }
          edge from parent node {Process 2}
        }
      }
      edge from parent node {Process 1}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I saw your comment and got it to work, but I'm glad you made an answer. :)